# iphone, ipad, android javascript print()

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ipad, printing

I'm trying to make my website iphone/ipad/android friendly.

Now, is there any way to make the javascript .print() function work on any of these devices?
Couldn't find an answer on this subject.

Looking forward to your replies,
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `window.print()` will work if you are using iOS 4.2 or later because [that version adds AirPrint support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356).

Android phones don't seem to have native support for printing yet however you might be interested in reading about [Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/overview). However that solution requires a "cloud enabled" printer.

Comment: Thank You, makes sense. Anything about android?

Comment: As I've said read about Cloud Print, I think that's what Google is focusing on at the moment. I haven't heard about native printing in Android however there are 3rd party apps that allow wireless printing (like PrintShare).

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript function print() will work fine on the iPhone and iPad.